# Magento Indexer issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have setup Cron on server to run custom import profile everyday at midnight. Thousand of products are either created or updated from this profile. The 'core_url_rewrite' table is going to be large day by day. Magento Indexer is not working properly when it runs from Magento backend. it stopped with the message.

I am trying to run Magento indexer from command line. but getting table "core_url_rewrite" lock exception. if this table is truncated and run Magento indexer, it's run fine but when Custom import profile update or insert product, it again break up and trigger same exception.

What would be best solution for it? It is not good idea to truncate table each time as Product are created/updated by Custom import profile daily.

Any good suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to increase the table space of table "core_url_rewrite". Following is a good article to solve this problem.

[The table is full](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html)

Comment: The link is not helpful. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're reaching either a memory or timeout limit for the reindexing of the URL rewrites.

Try using this extension to minimize the amount of time it takes to reindex URL Rewrites by only indexing what needs reindexing, not the full amount of data.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dn-d-patch-index-url-1.html